# Why is my gif lagging when I display it? (JFrame)

Tags: java, image, swing, gif, imageicon

I have a program where I was displaying a gif onto a `JFrame` but the GIF is extremely large so when I display it, it lags all the time. Is there any way I can get around this and have the gif display without lag?

Here is the code I have:

```
ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("res/" + ("Animations/" + "Untitled 2" + ".gif"));
back = new ImageIcon(back.getImage().getScaledInstance((int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()), (int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
Icon icon = back;

background = new JLabel(icon);
```

`background` is just a `JPanel` that holds this `JLabel` and from there it is added to the frame and displayed.

Comment: Does the gif lag when you look at it in a photo viewer?

Comment: No it does not lag in a photo viewer.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Post your gif in the forum so other can try testing your code to see if they have the same problem.

Comment: Resizing an image takes significant computing power. Better to have it at the correct size to begin with.